# Solr log file location on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, logging, tomcat, solr

I have installed Solr in Tomcat on my Ubuntu box.

After making some changes to the schema.xml configuration file, I get the following error when accessing the web interface of Solr:

> HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr
>   configuration. **Check your log files
>   for more detailed information on what
>   may be wrong.** If you want solr to
>   continue after configuration errors,
>   change:
>   false
>   in null
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   QueryElevationComponent requires the
>   schema to have a uniqueKeyField
>   implemented using StrField at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:157)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:508)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:589)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

My question is: Where does this logfile reside? I looked at /var/log/tomcat6/ but there was nothing (just a few files with no relevant question). I couldn't find any Solr-related logfiles either.

Is it because logging is not enabled in Tomcat6 by default? If so - how do I enable it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't find the log but managed to solve the problem by looking at the above snippet.

> QueryElevationComponent requires the schema to have a uniqueKeyField implemented using StrField

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu `solr.log` file resides at `/var/log/` folder
to see log file you can use following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/solr.log
```